# Why in Pubspec.lock flutter sdk is under version: "0.0.0"? How to safely lock a flutter version?

Tags: flutter, dart, yaml

I was helping to debug a test game app. I had a deep dive in packages. One thing that i am still puzzled about and cannot find proper documentation on stack overflow and official documentation... is the lines of codes that display **flutter version: "0.0.0"** while it is obviously not.

In **pubspec.lock** all the packages are properly up-to-date like this one:

```
   dependency: "direct main"
   description:
     name: audioplayers
     url: "https://pub.dartlang.org"
   source: hosted
   version: "0.14.2"
```

But is not for flutter

```
    dependency: "direct main"
    description: flutter
    source: sdk
    version: "0.0.0" 
...
flutter_test:
    dependency: "direct dev"
    description: flutter
    source: sdk
    version: "0.0.0"
  flutter_web_plugins:
    dependency: transitive
    description: flutter
    source: sdk
    version: "0.0.0"
```

then at the very bottom of there is

```
sdks:
  dart: ">=2.6.0 <3.0.0"
  flutter: ">=1.12.13+hotfix.4 <2.0.0"
```

Also in **pubspec.yaml**

Dart is constrained this way

```
  sdk: ">=2.3.0 <3.0.0"
```

while flutter is not

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
```

**Confused**

We compared our code to different source code on github and saw similar behaviors.
For example:
https://github.com/japalekhin/langaw/blob/master/pubspec.lock

https://github.com/fireship-io/183-flutter-draggable-game/blob/master/pubspec.lock

- To fix a version of flutter - can we edit the pubspec.lock line at the bottom? Would that create instability?
- Any documentation, explanations about what is happening under the hood? and why having a **version: "0.0.0"** in the code?

Comment: I have the same question as well, confused the version `0.0.0`. Also, I upgraded `flutter sdk` from `1.12.13+hotfix.4` to `1.12.13+hotfix.9` but the `pubspec.lock` file still shows `1.12.13+hotfix.4`. Then I changed the sdk version directly in `pubspec.lock` file and no issue. But I'm not sure if it's the right way to upgrade sdk version inside the project.

Comment: Anyone has found anything useful yet?

Comment: I agree that this will create inestability, if you install the thing in the future maybe the version is not compatible with some other dependency or introduce runtime issues in that mater, I dont get why they create the versions like this

Comment: Regarding "why having a version: "0.0.0" in the code?" This snippet from the official doc might have a lead. "Every package has a version. A version number is required to host your package on the pub.dev site, but can be omitted for local-only packages. If you omit it, your package is implicitly versioned 0.0.0." https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec