# sdk version solving failed error on executing code

Tags: flutter

I am beginner in flutter. Doing a course from Udemy but facing lots of problems.I am making shop app.

The current Flutter SDK version is 0.0.0-unknown.

I'm getting the below error when I run it in Android Studio

> Because shop_app depends on provider >=4.0.0-dev which requires
> Flutter SDK version >=1.12.1, version solving failed. pub get failed
> (1; Because shop_app depends on provider >=4.0.0-dev which requires
> Flutter SDK version >=1.12.1, version solving failed.)

Comment: post the pubspec.yaml file, this is unclear.  on assumption of errors there Put this flutter version in the pubspec.yaml file "Flutter SDK version >=1.12.1" or greater. Please do a udemy course that explains the pubspec files and their uses, don't directly jump into creation without the basics.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The current Flutter SDK version is 0.0.0-unknown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61691640/the-current-flutter-sdk-version-is-0-0-0-unknown)