# Application launch did not return a valid pair nor a launch error on Xcode after build succeed

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, dart

I have a problem with Xcode when I try to run a fluter application on the emulator.

The build goes `build succeed` but then a pop-up appears saying  `Application launch for 'com.<My-app>' did not return a valid pid nor a launch error. No such process`.

Before this error I got another error [Flutter version unknown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61691640/the-current-flutter-sdk-version-is-0-0-0-unknown) and I solved it with this command `xcode-select --install`.

These are the error details:

```
Details

Application launch for 'com.<My-app>' did not return a valid pid nor a launch error.
Domain: NSPOSIXErrorDomain
Code: 3
Failure Reason: No such process
User Info: {
    DVTErrorCreationDateKey = "2022-03-11 07:56:32 +0000";
    IDERunOperationFailingWorker = IDELaunchiPhoneSimulatorLauncher;
}
--

Analytics Event: com.apple.dt.IDERunOperationWorkerFinished : {
    "device_model" = "iPhone14,5";
    "device_osBuild" = "15.2 (19C51)";
    "device_platform" = "com.apple.platform.iphonesimulator";
    "launchSession_schemeCommand" = Run;
    "launchSession_state" = 1;
    "launchSession_targetArch" = arm64;
    "operation_duration_ms" = 232;
    "operation_errorCode" = 3;
    "operation_errorDomain" = NSPOSIXErrorDomain;
    "operation_errorWorker" = IDELaunchiPhoneSimulatorLauncher;
    "operation_name" = IDERunOperationWorkerGroup;
    "param_consoleMode" = 0;
    "param_debugger_attachToExtensions" = 0;
    "param_debugger_attachToXPC" = 0;
    "param_debugger_type" = 1;
    "param_destination_isProxy" = 0;
    "param_destination_platform" = "com.apple.platform.iphonesimulator";
    "param_diag_MainThreadChecker_stopOnIssue" = 0;
    "param_diag_MallocStackLogging_enableDuringAttach" = 0;
    "param_diag_MallocStackLogging_enableForXPC" = 1;
    "param_diag_allowLocationSimulation" = 1;
    "param_diag_gpu_frameCapture_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_gpu_shaderValidation_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_gpu_validation_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_memoryGraphOnResourceException" = 0;
    "param_diag_queueDebugging_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_runtimeProfile_generate" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_asan_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_tsan_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_tsan_stopOnIssue" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_ubsan_stopOnIssue" = 0;
    "param_diag_showNonLocalizedStrings" = 0;
    "param_diag_viewDebugging_enabled" = 0;
    "param_diag_viewDebugging_insertDylibOnLaunch" = 1;
    "param_install_style" = 0;
    "param_launcher_UID" = 2;
    "param_launcher_allowDeviceSensorReplayData" = 0;
    "param_launcher_kind" = 0;
    "param_launcher_style" = 0;
    "param_launcher_substyle" = 0;
    "param_runnable_appExtensionHostRunMode" = 0;
    "param_runnable_productType" = "com.apple.product-type.application";
    "param_runnable_swiftVersion" = "5.5.2";
    "param_runnable_type" = 2;
    "param_testing_launchedForTesting" = 0;
    "param_testing_suppressSimulatorApp" = 0;
    "param_testing_usingCLI" = 0;
    "sdk_canonicalName" = "iphonesimulator15.2";
    "sdk_osVersion" = "15.2";
    "sdk_variant" = iphonesimulator;
}
--


System Information

macOS Version 12.2.1 (Build 21D62)
Xcode 13.2.1 (19586) (Build 13C100)
Timestamp: 2022-03-11T08:56:32+01:00
```

Probably the problem is related also to the error that I got previously (Flutter version unknown) but it was a problem related to git.

Comment: Started to have same issue, app keeps crashing, doesn't matter if it's xcode, flutter or testflight.

Comment: I solved it by reinstall flutter and Xcode.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, even if I wasn't running it under Rosetta, I had to install it. To do that, run this script:

`softwareupdate --install-rosetta`

or this if you want to skip the license agreement:

`/usr/sbin/softwareupdate --install-rosetta --agree-to-license`

Answer (score 1):

It's an issue with authorization. Try this in the Terminal:

```
sudo DevToolsSecurity -enable
```

Comment: If it is going to happen again I will try and post the result here. Now I have reinstall flutter and I have no problems!