# is it posible to develop flutter app in expired licence mac os system

Tags: flutter, macos, dart

I am unable to setup mac sdk in my mac sierra 10.12 and getting version solving error and getiing unknown sdk isuue like "Flutter 0.0.0 unknown" in pub.get command fire

is this issue is getting cause of my mac expired licence version?

Comment: Hello! Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please make sure to read through the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), particularly the [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page. Improving your question may also help other users find and identify the problem.

Comment: its clear question for who develop flutter

Answer (score 0):

please try this question if you use mac pc
https://stackoverflow.com/a/70171060/17778563

and if it not working then Update your operating system.

Comment: thanks for answer i will try it