# Can't pub-get from pubspec.yaml file in Flutter app

Tags: flutter, dart, package

Every time I want to install a package it gives this error, how do I fix it? The error output is below:

The current Dart SDK version is 2.12.3.
The current Flutter SDK version is 0.0.0-unknown.

Because image_picker >=0.3.0 requires Flutter SDK version >=0.1.4 and image_picker <0.3.0 requires SDK version >=1.8.0 <2.0.0, image_picker is forbidden.
So, because firebase depends on image_picker any, version solving failed.
Running "flutter pub get" in firebase...
pub get failed (1; So, because firebase depends on image_picker any, version solving failed.)

Comment: Do any of the answers at [The current Flutter SDK version is 0.0.0-unknown](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61691640/) help?

Answer (score 0):

You check your flutter version and check that dependency version and change the dependency version otherwise remove the version.

Answer (score 0):

You have to either:

1. Downgrade the version of image_picker to match the flutter SDK version you currently use, or
2. Upgrade your flutter SDK version to a version above or equal to 1.8.0. (preferred solution).