# Gitlab Runner : The current Flutter SDK version is 0.0.0-unknown. - CI/CD

Tags: flutter, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner, cicd

I am trying to execute a .gitlabci.yml file with Gitlab Runner.
But I am getting this error message.

```
No dependencies changed.
1 package is discontinued.
57 packages have newer versions incompatible with dependency constraints.
Try `dart pub outdated` for more information.
Running "flutter pub get" in tardis...                          
The current Flutter SDK version is 0.0.0-unknown.
Because newApp depends on workmanager >=0.2.3 which requires Flutter SDK version >=1.10.0, version solving failed.
```

In short gitlab runner cannot detect my flutter version.

My flutter doctor screen:

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.10.5, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19044.1766], locale tr-TR)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 32.0.0)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Community 2019 16.9.1)
[√] Android Studio (version 2020.3)
[√] VS Code (version 1.68.1)
[√] Connected device (3 available)
[√] HTTP Host Availability

• No issues found!
```

How can i fix this?

Comment: Does this apply to you? https://stackoverflow.com/a/71399000/

Comment: unfortunately my problem is related to gitlab runner. I do not encounter a problem when I do these procedures myself.

Comment: My point is that your GitLab runner is doing something that is losing the tag information (perhaps such as by performing a shallow clone of the Flutter repository).  What is your GitLab runner doing?  How is it consuming the Flutter SDK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this problem. Perhaps, the GitLab runner cannot detect my flutter version because of the flutter SDK location. I moved the SDK from drive `D` to drive `C` and specified the new environment variable path. It works fine now.